# Google Slides Apps Script - User Ui Alerts and Prompts

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to add a script to a google slides presentation. So that, when the user opens the slides in edit mode, they are greeted with a prompt/alert. Asking if they would like some helpful reminders.
If the user clicks YES, then another alert/prompt displays a helpful reminder to the user (from an array of reminders at random).
If the user clicks NO or X a confirmation alert is provided.

The first part seems to be working. However, once the loop is triggered, if the user clicks NO or X the loop continues instead of ending with the confirmation message.

It seems to cycle through the array of reminders until the end of the array. I've included the script below.

```
function onOpen() {
  SlidesApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  showAlert();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SlidesApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var messages = [
    'SELF-ASSESSMENT: Be sure to complete the self-assessment before you commence work on this topic.',
    'BASIC PRESENTATION: Record your full name, title (for the slide), date and WALT onto all work slides',
    'CONTENT: Use a combination of text (your own words) and images for higher marks.',
    'EVIDENCE: There are 3 assessment objectives for each topic. Be sure to use at least 3 slides of work when presenting your evidence. One slide for each objective.',
    'SOURCES: Whenever you use an image, or refer to text that you found (elsewhere) relevant to the topic. Be sure to reference it, by adding a link to the source place holders.',
    'COLLABORATE: Use the SHARE tool, to share your topic journal with a work buddy. Be sure to set the permissions to VIEW. Have your work buddy do the same, and then check in on each others work, give each other feedback and keep the support going.',
    'SUPPORT: Use the support site/resource called CADD. There is a link to the support on Google Classroom',
    'HAND IN: Dont forget to click the HAND IN button on the assignment, before the due date!'
  ];

  var seenMessages = [];
  var count = 0;
  var randomIndex;
  var message;
  var today = new Date();
  var dateString = today.toLocaleDateString();
  var result = ui.alert(
      'Welcome to your computing journal. Today is ' + dateString + '. Would you like to see some helpful reminders, that might help you maximise your marks?',
      'Do you want another reminder?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.NO || result == ui.Button.X) {
    ui.alert('That\'s all for now, time to get on with your work!', 'OK', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  } else {
    while (count < 8) {
      if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);
        message = messages[randomIndex];
        if (!seenMessages.includes(message)) {
          seenMessages.push(message);
          ui.alert(message, 'Do you want another reminder?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried a number of alternative arrangements with the code, for moment this is about as close as I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showAlert() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const initA = ['Message0.', 'Message1', 'Message2', 'Message3', 'Message4', 'Message5', 'Message6', 'Message7'];
  let messages = initA.slice();
  var today = new Date();
  var dateString = today.toLocaleDateString();
  var result = ui.alert(
    'Intro ' + dateString + '. Would you like to see some helpful reminders, that might help you maximise our marks?', 'Do you want another reminder?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  while (messages.length > 0) {
    if (result == ui.Button.NO || result == ui.Button.X) {
      ui.alert('That\'s all for now, time to get on with your work!', 'OK', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
      return;
    } else {
      if (result == ui.Button.YES && messages.length > 0) {
        let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length);
        message = messages[idx];
        messages.splice(idx, 1);
        result = ui.alert(message, 'Do you want another reminder?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: You absolute star! With a couple of tweeks, that works perfect. Awesome, thank you so much. #faithinhumanityrestored